# Odd issue with PHP File Open/Write

Tags: php, cron, server-side

The issue I am having involves the use of fopen and fwrite to write to a text file on the server.  When I call my function from within a browser, the file is opened and written to as expected.  When I call the function from a scheduled task running on the server, the file is never written to though no error is ever thrown.  I don't believe it to be a permissions issue but I'm not sure what else it could be.  Has anyone else experienced something like this?

See the following snippet of code I'm using:

```
$file = "../logs/" . $token . ".txt";
$message = "Test Message";
fwrite(fopen($file, 'a+'), $message);
```

Comment: Have a look in your access and error logs. Could be a permission issue after all. What does your cron action job look like?

Comment: How you calling it on the scheduled task? Through curl or something like the php command line? Could be permission or could be that the current directory is different, so ../logs refers to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a script is executed by cron (I assume you mean cron with scheduling tasks) then the working directory of script will be the file system root `/`. Workaround: Use absolute paths in your script:

```
$file = "/path/to/logs/" . $token . ".txt";
$message = "Test Message";
fwrite(fopen($file, 'a+'), $message);
```

or use the [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant to build paths relative to the script source file:

```
$file = __DIR__ . "../logs/" . $token . ".txt";
$message = "Test Message";
fwrite(fopen($file, 'a+'), $message);
```

Comment: Yes, I did mean cron job.  Thank you for the correction, it slipped my mind.  I'll give this a shot.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I wound having to go with dirname(__FILE__) since this was 5.2, but the premise was the same.  Thanks for the idea, my mind slipped me on this one.

Comment: Yeah on versions before 5.3 it is `dirname(__FILE__)`